# ArcGIS JS API: Custom build, cors issue with mapserver url (501)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, arcgis-js-api

I followed the instructions to create a local copy of the arcgis js api 4.1 using bower. When I run my project (uses requirejs) I get a CORs error saying: 
OPTIONS http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer?f=json
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer?f=json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

This error is odd b/c the API should not make preflighted (options) request to this url, it should make a get request (originally thats what it does if you I don't use local copy of the API, instead using the CDN version). I have tried all the esri/config options to disable the cors but nothing seems to work. It doesn't load the map tiles. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Below is the config file for my project:

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
"jquery": 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min',
'esri/moment': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment',
"esri": "../lib/main", //If I use this URL, everything works http://js.arcgis.com/4.1/esri
"dojo": 'http://js.arcgis.com/4.1/dojo',
"dojox": 'http://js.arcgis.com/4.1/dojox'
},
bundles: {
"esri": ["esri/Color",
    "esri/geometry/Point",...]
},
...
});
```

Comment: any luck? i've got the same error but opposite situation... my local copy is fine but deployed version throws this error. I also have tried changing the CORS config options with no avail.

Comment: @Entrabiter I was able to solve it by downloading the dojo folder and copying it to my local project, then I had to add all the dojo paths that were required by esri to make it work. So in the config file instead of the dojo URL I have this: `"dojo/has": '../lib/dojo/has', 'dojo/domReady':'../lib/dojo/domReady', 'dojo/request': '../lib/dojo/request', ...`